# swap pandas column to values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe- got it from API so don't have much control over the structure of it- similar like this:

[image]

I want to have datetime a column and value as another column. Any hints?

Comment: What about `df.T`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny , lol I didn't know about it! and after T how to move index to column?

Comment: user df.reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use T to transform the dataframe and then reseindex to create a new index column and keep the current column you may need to change its name form index

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Comment: It puts time as a first row in the df

Comment: Found it to move it to header: df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2[1:]